# Python: how to unpack more than one value in a for?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, unpack

I'm trying to unpack two values in a for:

```
def getDiagonal(self):
    diagonal = [(r, c) for (r,c) in range(0, len(self.matrix)), range(0, len(self.matrix[0]))]
    return diagonal
```

And gives this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixModule.py", line 4, in <module>
    print m.getDiagonal()
  File "C:\Users\Capinzal\Google Drive\ProgramaþÒo\Matrix\matrix.py", line 46, in getDiagonal
    diagonal = [(r, c) for (r,c) in range(0, len(self.matrix)), range(0, len(self.matrix[0]))]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking it out into a simpler loop, so you can troubleshoot more easily, before trying to make it one line? From the looks of things you don't quite get how nested loops work in list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zip()`:

```
diagonal = [(r, c) for (r,c) in zip(range(len(self.matrix)), range(len(self.matrix[0])))]
```

That said, if you just want the `tuple` anyway, there's no need to unpack it or even make a comprehension, although you would still need `zip()`:

```
diagonal = list(zip(range(len(self.matrix)), range(len(self.matrix[0]))))
```

You can also omit the `0` for the `range` object, as that's the default start value. You'd need it if you wanted to specify a custom step value.